# Where or how to find the document root when launching localhost

Tags: php, localhost

I'm fairly new to programming in general and even more on PHP, so basically I'm following this tutorial on how to print "Hello World" on a localhost but looking at the tutorial I see that the document root is shown when the localhost is launched compared to mine showing less information. So I'm unable to save my program in the right location since i can't seem to figure out where is that document root.

Comment: Which server are using (e.g. xampp, wamp, etc.) and which OS (e.g. windows, linux, etc)?

Comment: _"I see that the document root is shown when the localhost is launched"_ - from that I am guessing, that you are talking about PHP's own built-in server, https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php ? As is explained on that page, it uses the current directory you are starting the server in by default; or you can also use the `-t` parameter to explicitly specify which directory it should use as document root. (Relative paths will still refer to the directory you started it in.)

Answer (score 1):

Your document root is configured in Apache (assuming you use PHP through Apache httpd server here).

Look in your httpd.conf file, you will find directive `DocumentRoot`, which will show you what directory it uses.  It will most probably be something like `.../htdocs` or `.../www` or `.../html`.